# blank result problem with crystal report in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio, ASP.NET. In my project i should use crystal report. unfortunately
when i use crystal report in asp.net, the result is showing blank page.

#### My Html Code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Crystal Report From More Than One Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="70%" height="300px" align="center"
style="border: solid 2px gray;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="background-color: SkyBlue;">
<span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 18pt; color: Green;">Customer
Product Order Detail Report</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlReport" runat="server" Height="400px">
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
</asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

#### My CS Code (Code behind):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("EmployeeCrystalReport.rpt"));
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is Correct but you should do two steps more:

### 1) Copy The folder with name `crystalreportviewers13` on the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319` and past it into `project root folder` as below on visual studio:

**Right click on your project name, then select `Open Folder On File Explorer`**

[image]

**Paste the folder with name `crystalreportviewers13`on this address (Project Root)**

[image]

After paste that, come back to your solution in visual studio, if the folder is hidden, you can do this:

**Click `Show All File` button**

[image]

**then Right click on the folder with name `crystalreportviewers13` which no color icon and choose `Include In Project`**

[image]

### 2) Add this javascript on your html head page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"></script>
```

## ENJOY!